# Django poll tutorial AttributeError

Tags: python, django

I've ran into problem with Django Poll [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial02/). For some reason, I keep getting

> AttributeError: 'Question' object has no attribute 'question_text'

I've been following tutorial step by step, not sure what went wrong.

Mmodels.py:

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

class Question(models.Model):
    # ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

class Choice(models.Model):
    # ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Comment: Well, is `question_text` a field of of `Question`?

Comment: @schwobaseggl `return self.question_text` <- this?

Comment: Yup. For this to work, `question_text` must be a field (or property) on the `Question` model. You are not showing those fields, so how can we tell you?

Comment: @schwobaseggl `question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)` <- is this the one? I thought this line should've been deleted with the new def

Comment: Nah, your `__str__` is merely accessing the contents of that field. It is abolutely mandatory that you keep it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess fields are missing from you model definition. As per django tutorial that you are referring models looks like this.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

If you place these, you will not face that error.